# Multiple variable quadratic equation with congruence

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quadratics, gcd-and-lcm

I have the following equation:

- $A^2-3B^2+7C^2-21D^2=0$

and I have to prove that it does not have any non-trivial solution in $\mathbb{Z}^4$
. Using Congruence I deduced that $X,Z \equiv 0$ (mod $3$) and then plugging it into the forms $X^2 = 9D^2$ and $Z=9E^2$ means that the equation "reproduces" itself with a factor before it. After this I don't know how to proceed.

Does $gcd(1,-3,7,21) = 1 $ have any part to play in this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If there is a solution with not all of $A,B,C,D$  zero    leads to this:  there is then an integer solution with $\gcd(A,B,C,D) = 1.$ So:  if $x^2 - 3 y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 7,$  what are the possible values of $x,y \pmod 7  \; ? \; \; $

Comment: It can only take $0$, so both multiples of 7

Comment: so   what do you know about $A,B$

Comment: That the $gcd(A,B)\neq 1$?

Comment: yes, but there is more to it: both are divisible by $7$   so the squares are divisible by $49.$  Concretely, we may write $A=7a$   and $B=7b.$  Your equation becomes $$49 a^2 - 147 b^2 + 7 C^2  - 21 D^2 = 0$$ What do you get if you factor out the common $7$

Comment: That it reproduces itself again, so $A^2-3B^2+7C^2-21D^2 = 7(C^2-3D^2+7a^2-21b^2)$ , similar to above but mod 7 instead of mod 3

Comment: Good. And that expression must be zero. So, what do you know about $C^2 - 3 D^2 $

Comment: That i can use them to reproduce it again but instead with a factor of 49. Since I can go to infinity with that does that mean it's not possible ?

Comment: I like to stop the infinite descent there;  the key observation was that there is a solution with $\gcd(A,B,C,D) = 1$ So far,  $C^2 - 3 D^2$  is divisible by $7.$   What does this tell us about $C,D$

Comment: Ah yes, that they're also multiples of 7, so $gcd(C,D) = 7$ so that means it doesn't have non-trivial solution because $gcd(A,B,C,D)\geq 7$ Is there a name for this theorem?

Comment: yes. The quadratic form is called anisotropic in the 7-adic numbers and in the 3-adic numbers. The conclusion is that $A,B,C,D$ are all divisible by $7,$   contradicting the assumption that a coprime solution is possible. Tell you what, why don't you write up a self-answer, this time use $3$ instead: **starting over,** we see that $A^2 + 7 C^2 $   is divisible by $3.$   What do we know about $A,C.$  And so on...  numbers a little easier this way

Comment: Socrates Lives!

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thanks.   I don't often get through the whole business before someone plops down a full answer.